# Read heads per cylinder with int 13h function 8

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader

I am trying to understand how to get "heads per cylinder" using int 13h function 8.

Wikipedia states that

> DH = logical last index of heads = number_of - 1 (because index starts with 0)

Is this the "heads per cylinder" or the total number of heads? (that value +1 to get number of)

I am currently assuming that it is the "heads per cylinder" and using this formula:

```
C = LBA ÷ (HPC × SPT)
H = (LBA ÷ SPT) mod HPC
S = (LBA mod SPT) + 1
```

I am using int 13h function 2 to read the sectors from disk. Using the SPT (63) and HPC (16) acquired from function 8, I am able to read from a disk with 2015 sectors or less. As soon as I require the cylinder value to be 2 it will not work, unless I read from a disk with minimum 3024 sectors. However, I am able to read across the track boundary to get the sectors above 2015, using a disk with less than 3024 sectors. It is only when I manually specify cylinder 2 that it requires the disk to be minimum 3024 sectors.

That is why I believe it has something to do with a wrong HPC value.
It is a bootloader and it is running in real mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't directly answer your question, but if you are not using a floppy drive (who is?) then consider switching to the LBA functions and forget this obsolete mess :)

Comment: DH will contain the number of heads per cylinder. I hope you are aware that when it comes to cylinders (and Int 13h/ah=2 and ah=8), cylinders are 10 bit values. (0 to 1023). The bottom 8 bits are in CH and the top 2 bits are the top 2 bits in CL.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am aware of that. DH contains 0xff, it is correct to add 1 to get the HPC right?

Comment: A value of 0xff is 255 for 256 heads per cylinder (0xff+1)

Comment: I ment 0xf, sorry

Comment: A value of 0xf would be 16 heads per cylinder yes (0x0f+1)

Comment: It is very likely that if you are dealing with disk images (and not physical media to have partial disk sizes). What you are experiencing may be a limitation of the environment you are running in.

Comment: So, reading sector 2016 should equal to C = 2, H = 0, S = 1; using the formula. Which is not working.

Comment: I just tried using Bochs instead of Qemu, and it is actually workign in Bochs. Both are using SeaBios though.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use INT 13h/08h. It's not reliable for floppy drives, you need to check what the media itself says its been formatted as, and unnecessary for hard disks since as Jester suggested you can use LBA addressing instead.

Comment: I'm assuming that the OP is in fact using hard drives since I don't know of any floppy format that uses 16 head per cylinder. Using Int 13h/ah=2 you will of course be limited to accessing hard drives up to 845571686 bytes (1024*63*256*512) assuming BIOSes after about 1994. What Jester and Ross are saying is if you are using non floppy media then most likely modern hardware has support for LBA directly - usually through the extended disk BIOS interrupts like INT 13h AH=42h. You can use INT 13h AH=41h to check if this extension is present.

Comment: If you are creating disk image sizes and using CHS I recommend you at least make the sizes of the images a multiple of (HPC * SPT * 512). If you are reading disk images with cylinder of 2 then you should at least use a disk image size of (2+1)*(HPC*SPT*512). Some BIOS and virtual environments may not work well with disk images size that are partial.

Comment: On a side not some BIOS implementations won't even allow you to read across a track boundary. It is something that is discouraged for maximum compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, that padding seems to do the trick